# Any #define or similar to differenciate between development versions and adhoc/release?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4.2

I'm developing an app for the iPhone, and I would like to have some defines in development version but with another value in adhoc and release (app store) version.

Now I'm using something like:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define kRemainingTimeBeforeCancellingInBackground 590  
#else
#define kRemainingTimeBeforeCancellingInBackground 60 
#endif
```

But it seems DEBUG is also defined in adhoc version.

Any idea or suggestion?
I wouldn't like to modify my project settings, as I'm using an integration server which is not mine.
Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: does `#if DEBUG` with 0 or 1 value work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no way to do what what you want without modifying the project. Based on what you've posted so far, it looks like removing the DEBUG flag from your adhoc build settings would be the proper solution. This is something you should talk over with your teammates and the owner of the integration process.

Comment: I created a new project from scratch and added this:
#ifdef DEBUG 
    NSLog(@"debug activated");
#else 
    NSLog(@"debug deactivated");
#endif
and it seems DEBUG macro is defined by default in the new projects, so nobody add it in my current project.
Is there any Apple document where I can see default defines? Thanks.

Comment: If you look at the build settings for your project, you can see the project-specific defines. It's under the "Preprocessing Macros" setting.